# How to add multiple core plot plots on one screen

Tags: ios, core-plot

Ok I'm stumped. I'm trying to use Core Plot 1.2 in my iOS app and I am trying to add two plots onto one screen. My code for my View Controller is below. There is a NIB file too but it is empty - the default view in just a UIView. I create two subviews of type CPTGraphHostingView, I add these as suvviews of self.view and then I create the graphs. In the code below I even commented out the method that creates one of the graphs to see if I could even get one graph to display, but all I get is a blank white screen.

I am using a simple X**2 function for testing purposes for each plot.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to get say 2 or 3 separate XY style plots onto a single screen?

```
@interface SensorPlotSecondViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>
{
    CPTGraphHostingView *accelSubview;
    CPTGraphHostingView *gyroSubview;
    CPTGraphHostingView *magSubview;

    CPTXYGraph *accelGraph;
    CPTXYGraph *gyroGraph;
    CPTXYGraph *magGraph;
}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot;

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

@end


@implementation SensorPlotSecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Second", @"Second");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];

        CGRect frm1=CGRectMake(0,0,320,150);
        accelSubview=[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frm1];
        [self.view addSubview:accelSubview];

        CGRect frm2=CGRectMake(0,150,320,150);
        gyroSubview=[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frm2];
        [self.view addSubview:gyroSubview];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self createAccelGraph];

    //[self createGyroGraph];
}

-(void)createAccelGraph
{
    accelGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: accelSubview.bounds];

    //CPTTheme *theme=[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
    //[accelGraph applyTheme:theme];

    accelGraph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)accelSubview;
    hostingView.hostedGraph=accelGraph;
    accelGraph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
    accelGraph.paddingTop = 0.0;
    accelGraph.paddingRight = 0.0;
    accelGraph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    //accelGraph.fill=nil;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)accelGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(30)];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)accelGraph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");

    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;

    axisSet.xAxis.visibleAxisRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"10")];

    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;

    axisSet.yAxis.visibleAxisRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"25")];

    accelGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 40.0;
    accelGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 80.0;
    accelGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 40.0;
    accelGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 300.0;

    CPTScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:accelSubview.bounds] autorelease];
    //CPTScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"X Squared Plot";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *dataLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle=dataLineStyle;
    xSquaredPlot.dataSource = self;

    [accelGraph addPlot:xSquaredPlot];

    CPTPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
    //xSquaredPlot.defaultPlotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;
    xSquaredPlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;

    /****
     CPTScatterPlot *xInversePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
     xInversePlot.identifier = @"X Inverse Plot";

     CPTMutableLineStyle *dataLineStyle2 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
     dataLineStyle2.lineWidth = 1.0f;
     dataLineStyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
     xInversePlot.dataLineStyle=dataLineStyle2;
     xInversePlot.dataSource = self;
     [accelGraph addPlot:xInversePlot];
     ****/

}

-(void)createGyroGraph
{
    gyroGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: gyroSubview.bounds];

    CPTTheme *theme=[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
    [gyroGraph applyTheme:theme];

    gyroGraph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)gyroSubview;
    hostingView.hostedGraph=gyroGraph;
    gyroGraph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
    gyroGraph.paddingTop = 0.0;
    gyroGraph.paddingRight = 0.0;
    gyroGraph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    gyroGraph.fill=nil;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)gyroGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(30)];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)gyroGraph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");

    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;

    axisSet.xAxis.visibleAxisRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"10")];

    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;

    axisSet.yAxis.visibleAxisRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"0") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"25")];

    gyroGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 40.0;
    gyroGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 200.0;
    gyroGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 40.0;
    gyroGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 150.0;

    CPTScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:gyroSubview.bounds] autorelease];
    //CPTScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"X Squared Plot";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *dataLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle=dataLineStyle;
    xSquaredPlot.dataSource = self;

    [gyroGraph addPlot:xSquaredPlot];

    CPTPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
    //xSquaredPlot.defaultPlotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;
    xSquaredPlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;

    /****
     CPTScatterPlot *xInversePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
     xInversePlot.identifier = @"X Inverse Plot";

     CPTMutableLineStyle *dataLineStyle2 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
     dataLineStyle2.lineWidth = 1.0f;
     dataLineStyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
     xInversePlot.dataLineStyle=dataLineStyle2;
     xInversePlot.dataSource = self;
     [accelGraph addPlot:xInversePlot];
     ****/

}
```

Comment: Advice for future: find most appropriate example in corePlot demo project and modify it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Your padding on the plot area frame is too big. The graph is only 150 pixels high, yet you're trying to inset the plot area by 380 pixels, leaving no room to draw the plots.